# Delete files in Windows>Temp>tmp0000* repertories : Windows 8.1

Tags: windows

I do not have enough space on my disk, I would like to know if I can delete the Temp files of the `Windows directory>Temp>tmp0000*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, anything in that temp directory is safe to delete.

All they are created for is to temporarily contain information and is not required to have on your hard-drive constantly.